# Showing that $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x \rangle}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x-1 \rangle}$ are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}[x]$ modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ring-isomorphism, module-isomorphism

I'm trying to solve an exercise which asks me to prove that $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x \rangle}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x-1 \rangle}$ are isomorphic as rings, but not as $\mathbb{R}[x]$ modules.

It's easy to show they're isomorphic as rings - you can either do it directly or use the first isomorphism theorem for rings to show they're both isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure how to approach showing that they're not isomorphic as modules though - it seems natural to try to prove it by contradiction, but if I assume there is an isomorphism I'm struggling to see where the contradiction comes from.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The scalar $x$ behaves very differently in $\mathbb R[x]/(x)$ then it does in $\mathbb R[x]/(x-1)$. If they were isomorphic as $\mathbb R[x]$ modules, this scalar should behave the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: what is $x \cdot 1$ in each of these?

Comment: Could you expand this answer please? Not for the OP, but other viewers like me.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is an $R[x]$-module homomorphism between the two modules in question, where does $x \cdot 1$ go? There are two possible answers to this question.

Comment: Oh, Silly me! So, $\phi(x + \langle x \rangle) = \phi(\langle x \rangle)= \langle x+1 \rangle$ and at the same $\phi(x + \langle x \rangle)= x \varphi(1+\langle x \rangle) = x\cdot (1 + \langle x-1 \rangle)$ because $x$ is a scalar. Right? (+1)

Comment: Are $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R[x]/(x)$ isomorphic as $\mathbb R[x]$ modules?

Comment: @AlJebr: what is the action of $x$ on $\mathbb{R}$? If it doesn't act as $0$, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

If $φ$ is an $R[x]$-module homomorphism from $R[x]/⟨x⟩$ to $R[x]/⟨x−1⟩$

By definition $φ(x⋅1)=x⋅φ(1)$.

Scalar multiplication is defined as $x=0$ in $R[x]/⟨x⟩$ and $x=1$ in $R[x]/⟨x-1⟩$

So $LHS = φ(0*1)=φ(0), RHS = 1*φ(1)=φ(1)$