# Why does the argument that $\mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle x^{2}\rangle \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle x^{2} - 1\rangle $ not apply in $\mathbb{Z_2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

So I have an exercise asking if $\mathbb{Q}{[x]} / \langle x^{2}\rangle  \simeq \mathbb{Q}{[x]} / \langle x^{2} - 1\rangle $ and if $\mathbb{Z_2}{[x]} / \langle x^{2}\rangle  \simeq \mathbb{Z_2}{[x]} / \langle x^{2} - 1\rangle $. My opinion is yes for $\mathbb{Q}$ and no for $\mathbb{Z_2}$, using contradiction:

Suppose we have an isomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Q}{[x]} / \langle x^{2}\rangle  \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}{[x]} / \langle x^{2} - 1\rangle $, that implies $\phi(x^{2}) = \phi(0) = 0 \implies \phi^{-1}(0) = \phi(x^{2}) = 0$, which is not possible since $\phi^{-1}(x^{2}) = 1$, it will work in $\mathbb{Q}$ but we have $0 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

Could someone please explain to me how to do this?

Comment: I think you have it backwards, and in any case $0 \neq 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (which I presume you mean, not the 2-adics. Hint: think about Freshman's Dream

Comment: Use `$\langle x\rangle$` for $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: Usually, we write $\Bbb Q[x]$, not $\Bbb Q_{[x]}$.

Comment: @bounceback i dont understand your hint tbh

Comment: You are wrong in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to Vercassivelaunos for the correction. My previous answer was quite far off.)

Define a homomorphism of rings (check it's well-defined)
$$
\varphi \colon k[x] \to k[y]/(y^2-1),  
x \mapsto y-1, 1 \mapsto 1.
$$

In characteristic 2, $$y^2 -1 = 0 \iff (y-1)^2 = 0 \iff y = 1,$$
so the kernel is $(x^2)$, and apply the fundamental homomorphism theorem to conclude.

In characteristic zero this map $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism. In fact, you should convince yourself that however we write down a map it cannot possibly be an isomorphism (see [Showing that $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x \rangle}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x-1 \rangle}$ are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}[x]$ modules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122036/showing-that-frac-mathbbrx-langle-x-rangle-and-frac-mathbbrx?rq=1)).

Comment: Higher order polynomials shouldn't be possible in $\mathbb Q/(X^2-1)$, either, since $x^n=1$ for even $n$ and $x^n=x$ for odd $n$. So all higher order polynomials can be reduced to linear ones. Similar reasoning can be applied to $R[X]/(p)$ for any commutative ring $R$ and polynomial $p\in R[X]$. The "order" of polynomials in the quotient can always be reduced to one less than the order of $p$.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected I may have done something wrong. Let me try and correct my answer to take your feedback into account.

Comment: Further feedback very much welcome

Comment: I think you meant to write that the kernel is $(x^2)$ in characteristic 2. In characteristic $0$, $x^2\mapsto (x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1=2(x+1)\neq0$. And you should probably add that the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms now tells us that $k[x]/(x^2)\cong k[x]/(x^2-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{Nil}(\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{x^2-1})$,$\text{Nil}(\frac{\Bbb Z_2[x]}{x^2-1})$ are trivial nilradicals because where $\Bbb F$ is a field we must have  $$f(x)\in\text{Nil}\big(\frac{\Bbb F[x]}{\langle x^2-1\rangle}\big)\iff f(x)\in\text{Nil}\big(\frac{\Bbb F[x]}{\langle x-1\rangle}\big)\;\land\;f(x)\in\text{Nil}\big(\frac{\Bbb F[x]}{\langle x+1\rangle}\big)$$ $$\therefore\;f(x)\in\text{Nil}\big(\frac{\Bbb F[x]}{\langle x^2-1\rangle}\big)\iff f(x)=0+\langle x^2-1\rangle$$ $x\pm 1$ are irreducibles, $\langle x\pm 1\rangle$ are maximal and thus $\frac{\Bbb F[x]}{\langle x\pm 1\rangle}$ are fields but $$X_1:=x+\langle x^2\rangle_{\Bbb Q[x]}\in\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}\;\;\text{and}\;\;X_2:=x+\langle x^2\rangle_{\Bbb Z_2[x]}\in\frac{\Bbb Z_2[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}$$ are non-trivial nilpotents as $$X_1^2=x^2+\langle x^2\rangle_{\Bbb Q[x]}=\langle x^2\rangle_{\Bbb Q[x]}\;\;\;\;\;X_2^2=x^2+\langle x^2\rangle_{\Bbb Z_2[x]}=\langle x^2\rangle_{\Bbb Z_2[x]}$$
Therefore $\text{Nil}(\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{x^2-1})$,$\text{Nil}(\frac{\Bbb Z_2[x]}{x^2-1})$ are trivial but $\text{Nil}(\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}),\text{Nil}(\frac{\Bbb Z_2}{\langle x^2\rangle})$ are $\it{non}$-$\text{trivial}$. $$\therefore\;\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}\not\approx\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{\langle x^2-1\rangle}\;\land\;\frac{\Bbb Z_2[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}\not\approx\frac{\Bbb Z_2[x]}{\langle x^2-1\rangle}$$